# How to use filter, group by and agg function together in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe below:

```
  A         B       C
0 asia      1000    ab
1 africa    2000    ab
2 asia      4000    bc
3 asia      6000    cd
4 USA       200     ab
```

I'd like to filter for column A = asia and sum column B group by column C. I am trying to use:

```
agg = df[df['A'] = 'asia'].groupby('C')[['B']].sum()
```

But it only returns one row with column B and sum amount of column C. I'd like to return the whole dataframe. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Almost there `df[df.A=='asia'].groupby('C')['B'].sum().reset_index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df1 = df[df['A'] == 'asia'].groupby(['A', 'C'], as_index=False).sum()
print(df1)

      A   C     B
0  asia  ab  1000
1  asia  bc  4000
2  asia  cd  6000
```

Comment: I think this would work. By the way, how to filter for multiple columns？I am trying to use &, but the system keeps showing me error

Comment: You have to use braces
`df[(df['A'] == 'asia') & (df['A'] == 'africa')]`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in two steps as follows.

```
group = [('asia', data['B'].sum(), c) for c, data in df[df['A'] = 'asia'].groupby('C')]
df_new = pd.DataFrame(group, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```